# How to process a yuv file

Tags: matlab, video, converters, video-processing, yuv

There are a lot of things I have to do with my yuv file.

1. Convert it to avi file format.
2. How can I alter the resolution of a yuv sequence? Say, qcif to cif?

I'm going to use it for video processing in Matlab.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in the File Exchange called [YUV-File to Matlab-Movie](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11252-yuv-file-to-matlab-movie) that will convert your file. To modify the properties of a movie, you can simply create a new one by modifying/copying each frame (see [Approaches to create a video in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051307/approaches-to-create-a-video-in-matlab)).