# (MATLAB R2013a) Saving video using VideoWriter but can't save the labels and title

Tags: matlab

Sorry for my bad English :( hope you guys can understand what my problems are.

Fist this is my code of a double pendulum simulation.

```
close all;clear all; clc;

theta1          = -pi;
dtheta1         = -5;
theta2          = pi/2;
dtheta2         = 10;

m1              = 1;
m2              = 1.7;
r1              = 1.3;
r2              = 1;
g               = 9.8;

duration        = 5;

y0 = [theta1;dtheta1;theta2;dtheta2;m1;m2;r1;r2;g];

[t,y] = ode45(@eqns,[0 duration],y0);

theta1          = wrapToPi(y(:,1));
dtheta1         = y(:,2);
theta2          = wrapToPi(y(:,3));
dtheta2         = y(:,4);

fps             = round(length(theta1)/duration);

X = zeros(length(theta1),3);
Y = zeros(length(theta1),3);

for i=1:length(theta1)
    X(i,:)=[0,r1*sin(theta1(i)),r1*sin(theta1(i))+r2*sin(theta2(i))];
    Y(i,:)=[0,-r1*cos(theta1(i)),-r1*cos(theta1(i))-r2*cos(theta2(i))];
end

mov = VideoWriter('Double Pendulum','MPEG-4');
set(mov,'FrameRate',fps,'Quality',100);
open(mov)

h = plot(0,0,'MarkerSize',30,'Marker','.','LineWidth',1.4);
range = 1.25*(r1+r2);axis([-range range -range range]); axis square;
xlabel('x');ylabel('y');title('Double Pendulum');

set(gca,'nextplot','replacechildren');
textlocation = range * 0.7;
hold on

for i=2:length(theta1)
    set(h,'XData',X(i,:),'YData',Y(i,:));
    plot([X(i-1,3) X(i,3)],[Y(i-1,3) Y(i,3)],'r')
    plot(X(i,2),Y(i,2),'g')
    frame = getframe;
    writeVideo(mov,frame);
end

close(mov);
```

And here is the result,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7pyagcnhca6khb3/Double%20pendulum%20result.PNG

For some reason the labels and title aren't get recorded, and I also realize that the colour are really different from what I see in Matlab. I tried using 'Uncompressed AVI' instead of 'MPEG-4' is give me the best result in terms of colour and quality, but the file size is 50MB, with 'MPEG-4' the file size is only 560KB.

I want to know, is there any setting that will give me a a better coulor (closer to what I see in Matlab) with lower file size (I am quite happy with this mp4 quality) and the labels will get recorded.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The default quality for MPEG-4 videos (`VideoWriter.getProfiles()`) is only set at 75/100. Have you tried setting it to 100? It will increase file size a bit, but color accuracy may improve. Unfortunately MPEG-4/h.264 is not the best codec for most videos Matlab of figures (there are better h.264 versions/profiles, but Matlab seems to use port settings). You might try Motion JPEG 2000. Or, if you don't mind QuickTime, try my [`QTWriter`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16827218/2278029), which has codecs that are perfect for Matlab-type graphics. From there you could convert to other formats.

Comment: I use "set(mov,'FrameRate',fps,'Quality',100)" to set my quality to 100 already, but the colour still really bad. Thanks for you advice, I will try your QTWriter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask two questions:
 1. How to compress video without too much degradation in color quality
 2. How to capture the title and labels for each frame

I will answer only your second question:

If you read the manual for [`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) you'll see that by default it captures the current **axes**. In order to capture labels and title you need to capture the current **figure**. So, what you need is to replace `frame = getframe` by

```
frame = getframe( gcf );
```

Comment: This actually only gets the xlabel ylabel and the colorbar if its there, it does not get the title or for instance colorbar scaling.