# How I can create a movie from a bunch of plots

Tags: matlab, movie

I am really a beginner to make a  movie. I need to make a movie from a bunch of plots. How I can make it.
I have 8 plots , which are y versus x. I want to make movie based on x to see how y change with increasing x.

Please consider my matlab file is as below:

```
x=[1 1.2 1.4 2 3 4 5 7 9 10];
y1=[2.8 7.6 10.9 12.3 15.0 21 12.3 14.5 42.4 47.7];
y2=1e8.*[0.599e-7 0.607e-7 0.343e-7 0.3e-7 0.873e-8 0.578e-8 0.298e-8 0.725e-9 0.14e-8 0.478e-9];
y3=10.*[0.136 0.544 0.834 1.03 0.366 0.314 0.703 0.207 0.696 0.164];
y4=10.*[0.26 0.21 0.17 0.25 0.31 0.34 0.16 0.15 0.13 0.31];
y5=....
y6=...
y7=...
y8=[6 7.6 10.9 12.3 15.0 21 12.3 19.5 42.4 47.7 ];
plot(x,y1)
hold on 
plot(x,y2)
hold on 
plot(x,y3)
hold on 
plot(x,y4)
hold on 
plot(x,y5)
hold on 
plot(x,y6)
hold on 
...
plot(x,y8)
```

I wrote following as a simple example but it does not work:

```
clc;clear all;
x=[1 1.2 1.4 2 3 4 5 7 9 10];
y = zeros(4,10);
y(1,:)=[2.8 7.6 10.9 12.3 15.0 21 12.3 14.5 42.4 47.7  ];
y(2,:)=1e8.*[0.599e-7 0.607e-7 0.343e-7 0.3e-7 0.873e-8 0.578e-8 0.298e-8 0.725e-9 0.14e-8 0.478e-9];
y(3,:)=10.*[0.136 0.544 0.834 1.03 0.366 0.314 0.703 0.207 0.696 0.164 ];
y(4,:)=10.*[0.26 0.21 0.17 0.25 0.31 0.34 0.16 0.15 0.13 0.31 ];

figure;
hold on
for n = 1:10
    plot(x,y)
    M(n)=getframe; % get frame from the current figure;
end

movie(M,10); %plays movie M 10 times
```

In a nut shell , How I can make a movie like Fig. 3.2: in the following [link](http://www.physics.cit.ie/photonics/photonic_device_dynamics_group/Techniques.html)

Comment: File -> New Project. That should be enough to get you started?

Comment: Is it clear now? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I've added the matlab tag to your question, you might get some responses

Comment: possible duplicate of [Approaches to create a video in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051307/approaches-to-create-a-video-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

The basic code for making a movie from a given figure is like this:

```
figure;
hold on
for n = 1:20
    plot(1:10,n*(1:10))
    M(n)=getframe; % get frame from the current figure;
end

movie(M,10); %plays movie M 10 times
```

Look into the help files for `getframe` and `movie` to see what other options are available.  To save a movie out, see `movie2avi`.

Note that for a given figure you only need to call `hold on` once.  If all your `y` values are of the same length, then you can re-write your code/plotting more efficiently like this:

```
x=[1 1.2 1.4 2 3 4 5 7 9 10];
y = zeros(8,10);

% then this for each of your sets of y values
y(1,:) = [2.8 7.6 10.9 12.3 15.0 21 12.3 14.5 42.4 47.7 53 81.3 86.1];
...
y(8,:)=[6 7.6 10.9 12.3 15.0 21 12.3 19.5 42.4 47.7 53 81.3 86.1 ];

plot(x,y) % plots all the y's against x with automatic coloring
plot(x,y(n,:)) % plots just one set of y values against x
```

Comment: Thank you a lot.  How I can save final figure in order to show like movie in my presentation?

Comment: I wrote following as a simple example but it does not work: Please look at on my edited question

Comment: In your current loop you're just repeating `plot(x,y)` over and over so all the frames of the movie are the same.  That's why I showed the `plot(x,y(n,:))` syntax.  `n` is just a single number.

Comment: What I have to put "for n = 1:?" in the question mark place:

Comment: depends how many frames you have.  Why not try a few different numbers and see what happens?

Comment: How I can make a movie like Fig. 3.2: in the following [link](http://www.physics.cit.ie/photonics/photonic_device_dynamics_group/Techniques.html)