# How can I visualize the tracking of every non-zero elements in a 2D matrix?

Tags: matlab, visualization

I have a 2D matrix in which the elements are either 1 or 0.

[image]

As as time progresses, this matrix gets updated w.r.t. some other variables. The update is such that the '1' elements of matrix moves through the coordinates to aggregate itself to a particular location (may be centre of the 2D matrix).

So I would like to track the motion of each '1' elements towards the centre. How can I realize this?

Comment: You must have some equation or algorithm that predicts the location of each 1 at the next time step, I assume. Why don't you just save these time steps? Maybe I don;'t understand the problem

Comment: You can use timeseries as @TheodorBecker said or try this way: in your algorithm you have '1'. It moves at other place. Save some value, for example '-1' at previous place (not zero). This '-1' must works like '0' value (any new point can gets up at this place). But you set different colours for it when create plot. So, points will be black, tracks - red, for example.

Comment: Are you looking for something [animated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051307/approaches-to-create-a-video-in-matlab), or a 2d-Plot? Also, would it be possible to track each "one" as a single point with x-position and y-position?

Comment: @MartinJ.H. : Yes I am looking for something animated. The path of track must be traced as lines.

Comment: If you want the history of each point, you may have to manage a graphic objet and an array for each single point. How many `1` are you talking about ... and for how long (how many animation steps or frames ?)

Comment: @Hoki actually there are ~10,000 `1`s. The animation will be around ~1000000 iterations.

Comment: frames are much lesser.

Comment: wow, I based my answer on your figure with `1000` non-zeros elements. I tried it and it still run ok, but things may be a bit sluggish with 2x10,000 graphic objects. You may have to skip/average some of the iterations in less frames indeed.

Answer (score 3):

This answer will help you with the **visualisation** of your points and their movement history, but it does not handle the *tracking* of your non-zeros elements.

Let's start with sample data:

```
%% // sample data
nMax = 10 ;               %// Max size of matrice
M0 = randi([0 1],nMax) ;  %// populate with random "0" and "1"

[x,y] = find(M0==1) ;     %// find coordinates of "1"s
npt = numel(x) ;          %// how many have we got
```

Then we draw the initial state. I used 2 graphic objects per `1`: One single point display with a specific marker to show the "head" of the trace (the last position of the point), and one dotted fine line (with no markers) to show the history trace.

```
%% // Display initial state
hf = figure ; hax = axes('Nextplot','Add') ;

for ip = 1:npt
    %// draw the lasp point (the "head")
    hp(ip) = plot( x(ip) , y(ip) , 'Marker','o' , 'LineStyle','none' ) ;
    %// draw the history line (empty at the moment, will populate later)
    hl(ip) = plot( x(ip) , y(ip) , 'Marker','none' , 'LineStyle',':' ) ;
end

set( hax , 'XLim',[0 nMax],'YLim',[0 nMax]) %// to fix axis limits
```

Then the animation itself. To move the points, at each animation iteration I add a small quantity to the last coordinates. You'll have to replace that part with your own coordinate update.
Then I concatenate the new coordinate with the old ones, and update each graphic object:

```
%% // now do the animation
nHist = 30 ; %// number of history point to display on the trace

for animStep = 1:100
    %//                  Movement engine
    %// ---------------------------------------------------------
    %// Replace this block with your own point coordinate update
    x = [ x , x(:,end) + randi([-1 1],npt,1)/10 ] ;
    y = [ y , y(:,end) + randi([-1 1],npt,1)/10 ] ;
    x(x<0) = 0 ; x(x>nMax) = nMax ;   %// keep data within boundaries
    y(x<0) = 0 ; y(y>nMax) = nMax ;
    %// ---------------------------------------------------------


    %% // update display
    for ip = 1:npt
        %// update "Head" point
        set( hp(ip) , 'XData',x(ip,end)  ,'YData',y(ip,end) ) 

        %// update history trace
        idxTrace = max(1,size(x,2)-nHist):size(x,2) ;
        set( hl(ip) , 'XData',x(ip,idxTrace)  ,'YData',y(ip,idxTrace) ) 
    end
    drawnow
    pause(0.1)

end
```

Which produces the following:

[image: animpoint]

You can adjust the variable `nHist` to change the number of history points you will display.

You can also change the "head" marker to something smaller if you have too many of them in your matrix.