# Exporting and saving an animation as a Video File

Tags: matlab

```
count = 1;                              
R_Ball = 2;
initpos.x = 0;
initpos.y = 2.4;
initvel.x = 2;
initvel.y = 4;
gravity.x = 0;
gravity.y = 9.81;
restitution = 0.7;
GroundBall_friction = 0.2;
dt = 0.001;
pos.x = initpos.x; % initial position
pos.y = initpos.y; % initial position
vel.x = initvel.x; % initial velocity-x
vel.y = initvel.y; % initial velocity-y
t_arc = linspace(0,(2*vel.y)/gravity.y,2000);
for k =  1:2000

%Updating the ball's position
vel.x = vel.x;
vel.y = vel.y - gravity.y*t_arc(k);
pos.x = pos.x + vel.x*t_arc(k);
pos.y = pos.y + vel.y*t_arc(k) - (1/2)*gravity.y*(t_arc(k).^2);
if  vel.y < 0 && pos.y < 0
vel.y = (-1)*(restitution)*vel.y;
vel.x = vel.x + GroundBall_friction*(restitution - 1)*vel.x;
end
pos.y = max(0, pos.y);
clf;
subplot(2,1,1)
hold on
line([0 30],[0 0]);
rectangle('position', [pos.x pos.y R_Ball R_Ball],'Curvature',[1 1],'FaceColor','r');
posyy(count) = pos.y;
plot(posxx + 1/2*R_Ball, posyy + 1/2*R_Ball,'b');
axis([0 30 0 10]);
hold off
subplot(2,1,2)
hold on
velyy(count) = vel.y;
velxx(count) = vel.x;
plot(posxx,velxx,'r','LineWidth',2);
plot(posxx,velyy,'b','LineWidth',2);
count = count+1;
legend('Velocity.X','Velocity.Y');
hold off
axis([0 30 -10 10]);
%Refresh rate
pause(dt)
end
% save video as .mp4;
myVideo = VideoWriter('Boucing_Ball','mpeg-4');
myVideo.FrameRate = 60; % frames per second
open(myVideo);
writeVideo(myVideo,);
close(myVideo);
```

I'm slightly unaware on how to solve this problem. I want to export this animation and save it using the VideoWriter function in an MP4 format. But I'm new to writing animations so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as it is gives the following error:

`Undefined function or variable 'posxx'`

You should add the following code (before line 18): `posxx=0;`

In this thread [Approaches to create a video in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051307/approaches-to-create-a-video-in-matlab) you can get information on how to create a video using `writeVideo`. You should get the current frame and store it and then call the function.