# Movie in Matlab is cropped and doesn't show the full figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, movies

I am learning to make a movie in Matlab. I coped this piece of code from internet to make the movie. I am using OS X Mavericks and Matlab 2013a. I usually dock the figure windows. When I run the code I can see animation perfectly. When when I save the movie either by using  `movie2avi` or `VideoWriter` command. It doesn't record the movie with full frame of figure. Instead I see a little bit of the figure window and my Matlab desktop view. Can anyone help me with this?

```
 clear; 
close all;

% Creates a 2D Mesh to plot surface
x=linspace(0,1,100);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,x);

N=100; % Number of frames
for i = 1:N
% Example of plot 
Z = sin(2*pi*(X-i/N)).*sin(2*pi*(Y-i/N));
surf(X,Y,Z)
% Store the frame   
M(i)=getframe(gca); % leaving gcf out crops the frame in the movie.


end 

% myVideo = VideoWriter('wavemotion.avi');
% open(myVideo);
% writeVideo(myVideo,M)
% close(myVideo)


% Output the movie as an avi file
%movie2avi(M,'WaveMovie.avi');
```

Comment: I had the same problem. You can find the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161480/matlab-videowriter-creates-video-with-only-section-of-figure/31161824#31161824

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation of both `VideoWriter` and `movie2avi`, you need to add a few more instructions to your code.

First, you need to set the renderer for a nice display and set the axes that the next plot will reset only the children and not the entire axes:

```
set(gca,'nextplot','replacechildren');
set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer');
```

There is also an advice to preallocate the frame buffer:

```
M(N) = struct('cdata',[],'colormap',[]);
```

Finally, you just need to call `getframe` without any argmuent, as `gca` is the default argument.

On my computer (with Matlab 2013b), with these modifications and using `VideoWriter`, it works fine. With `movie2avi`, it does not work properly; I think I need to specify a compression codec to fix that.

Comment: I have copy pasted your solution but result is still the same. Do you also use Matlab on OS X?

Comment: No, on Windows, sorry. Maybe you need to choose a correct compression codec? I've read that this is quite different along OS...

Comment: Any place where I can get some info?

Comment: Take a look at this [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583538/problems-with-movie-file-creation-in-matlab), there may be a useful trick. Otherwise, I find that `axis tight` may work wrong; try to adjust the axes limits by hand.